# Turning a result from a query into a PHP variable

Tags: php

The query below is on a page where there is only one value for `$submissionid`.  Thus, the field `points` has only one value.

How can I turn the `points` from the query below into a regular PHP variable?

```
  $sqlStra = "SELECT points, submissionid
               FROM submission 
              WHERE submissionid = '$submissionid'";
```

**EDIT:** This is pulling from a MySQL database.

**EDIT II:** I want to `points` to equal a variable on the entire page, not just inside of a while loop.

Comment: Well, how do you execute the query in the first place? Also, be aware that this query is vulnerable to SQL injection unless you have sanitized the value of `$submissionid` (possibly with `intval`?) beforehand.

Comment: The answer depends heavily on which database and database library you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use an ORM library (I use the one that comes bundled with [Kohana](http://kohanaframework.org/)) to eliminate the possibility of SQL injections. However, assuming a database connection is already established, this code will do what you are looking for.

```
$resource = mysql_query("SELECT points, submissionid FROM submission WHERE submissionid = '$submissionid'");
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);
echo $result["points"];
```

If you don't have a MySQL database connection established, check out [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).

Answer (score 1):

In this way you can read all the points returned by your query.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlStra, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $points = $row["points"]);
}
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` takes a resource (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php), not the query directly. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll want to get a resource from that query and then give it to mysql_fetch_assoc, like so:

```
$res = mysql_query($sqlStra);

// If you **Know for sure** you'll only have one row:
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
$points = $row['points'];

//Otherwise, you're going to need to loop.
$array_of_all_points = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    // $row['points'] now has what you want. You can assign it normally, or can use
    // extract($row) to turn it into $points, which I would advise against personally.
    $points = $row['points'];
    $array_of_all_points[$row['submissionid']] = $row['points'];
}

echo $points; // This will be the last $row['points'] that was executed.
echo $array_of_all_points['thatsubmissionid']; // Will output the points for the given session id.
```

Also, that query isn't safe (if $submissionid comes from user input, it is vulnerable to SQL injection), you should use an ORM library as [iloveitaly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8541363/570006) mentions. (I use [Zend DB](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html), though it's not technically ORM by itself)

Edit:

As the comments point out, this depends on if you're actually using Mysql. If you're not, you can use the [PDO library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) to do your querying.

Comment: @ Cthos:  I want to `points` to equal a variable on the entire page, not just inside of a while loop.

Comment: @John - Right... the while loop is scoped to the current scope you're in.

Comment: @ Cthos if I say `$row['points'] = $points` within the while loop, can I go use `$points` outside of the loop?

Comment: @John - Yes, you can (assuming you meant `$points = $row['points']`). I've edited the answer to attempt to clarify your options. while loops do not have their own internal scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlStra = "SELECT points FROM submission WHERE submissionid = ?"; 

$statement = $connection->prepare($sqlStra);
$statement->bind_param('i', $submissionid);
$statement->bind_result($points);
$statement->execute();
$statement->fetch(); // this will create / populate $points
```